# Difference in groovy between calling a method

Tags: spring, hibernate, groovy

What is the difference under the hood in groovy between the calls of the function service.defects and service.getDefects()

```
@RequestMapping("/test1")
 ModelAndView getTest1() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView()
    mav.viewName = "test"
    List<Defect> defects = service.defects
    mav
}


 @RequestMapping("/test2")
  ModelAndView getTest2() {
     ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView()
     mav.viewName = "test"
     List<Defect> defects = service.getDefects()
     mav
 }
```

I was struggling with this problem for quite a while, and although I thought the calls where the same, they are not. In my scenario the call of service.defects caused a "org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread" exception (getDefects() is Transactional though).

Can anybody explain me what is going on under the hood when I call the method with "service.defects"

This is the stack trace I get:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:883)
    at org.hibernate.SessionFactory$getCurrentSession.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.dao.LogDBDao.getExceptionLogFileEntry(LogDBDao.groovy:35)
    at com.test.dao.ILogDBDao$getExceptionLogFileEntry.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.service.ImportLogsService.getIncidents(ImportLogsService.groovy:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1580)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3308)
    at com.test.service.ImportLogsService.getProperty(ImportLogsService.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
    at com.test.service.$Proxy27.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at com.test.controller.IncidentController.getIncidents(IncidentController.groovy:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is the type of `service`?  In Groovy `foo.bar` _usually_ means the same as `foo.getBar()` but certain classes modify that behaviour (e.g. on a `Map` a call to `theMap.class` means `theMap.get('class')` instead of `theMap.getClass()`).

Comment: Service is a custom class which has a method getDefects() which just delegates to a DAO which in turn gets defects from a DB. The application is running in a Spring context so might it be that Spring is modifying the behaviour when proxiing the objects?

Comment: If `service` is itself written in Groovy then yes, that's very possible.  It may be (I'm speculating here) that the Groovy `service.defects` becomes a call to something like `service.getProperty('defects')` which in turn eventually calls `service.getDefects()`, but if Spring is stepping in and proxying at the `getProperty` level rather than the `getDefects` level then you could see different behaviour.  The full stack trace of the error should give you a bit more insight.

Comment: You may be able to finesse it if `service` implements an interface written in Java and you use interface proxying (proxy-target-class="false") instead of CGLIB.

Comment: @IanRoberts I guess `service.getProperty('defects')` actually looks for a property `getDefects()` in the class if it is not explicitly written. In this case, OP has customized the accessor method, so I guess he has to call `getDefects` inside `getProperty` to make `service.defects` work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I edited my question and added the stacktrace. Implementing the interface in JAVA and using interface proxying didn't make any difference as far as I can tell

Comment: I guess interface proxying still hits `getProperty` because that's defined in the `GroovyObject` interface that all classes written in Groovy will implement automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Groovy class, a property access

```
service.defects
```

becomes a call to `service.getProperty("defects")`, the default implementation of which will ultimately delegate to `service.getDefects()`.  So working up that stack trace from the bottom, `IncidentController` calls `getProperty("incidents")` on the `service` object, which is a Spring AOP proxy.

```
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
at com.test.service.$Proxy27.getProperty(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:47)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
at com.test.controller.IncidentController.getIncidents(IncidentController.groovy:22)
```

That method is *not* marked as transactional, so Spring has no need to set up the transaction context before calling the method on the underlying object

```
at com.test.service.ImportLogsService.getProperty(ImportLogsService.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Now the `getProperty` implementation of `ImportLogsService` does the usual default behaviour and calls its own `getIncidents` method

```
at com.test.service.ImportLogsService.getIncidents(ImportLogsService.groovy:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1580)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3308)
```

Note that this is internal to the target service object, so does *not* go through the Spring transactional proxy layer again.  Thus, even if `getIncidents()` is marked as `@Transactional` the transaction interceptor is not called.  Finally `getIncidents()` calls into the DAO layer

```
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:883)
at org.hibernate.SessionFactory$getCurrentSession.call(Unknown Source)
at com.test.dao.LogDBDao.getExceptionLogFileEntry(LogDBDao.groovy:35)
at com.test.dao.ILogDBDao$getExceptionLogFileEntry.call(Unknown Source)
```

which fails because there's no context set up.

If you called `service.getIncidents()` in the first place then that method (which is marked transactional) would be the first point of entry into the Spring proxy, and the transaction context would be set up correctly.

Try annotating the whole `ImportLogsService` *class* as `@Transactional`, rather than just the individual methods.  This should cause the transaction interceptors to fire on `getProperty` as well as `getIncidents()`.